# Firebase Storage file download stops working after a while

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a simple trigger set on file upload to Firebase. It reads uploaded file, process it and saves results to database. It works for a while, after that it crashes and stops working. Usually uploading function helps. Does anybody have an idea what might be the reason? Am I getting out of memory or ... ?

Here is the code :

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const path = require('path');
const storage = new Storage();

exports.processLogs = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async (object) => {


    const filename = path.basename(object.name);
    const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket);


    try {
        await bucket.file(filename).download(async (err, contents) => {
               if (err) {
                        console.log('error', err);
                        return null
               }

               //Proces file and store into db
               // (...)

               bucket.file(filename).delete();

        });
    } catch(e){
            console.log('error',e)
    }

});
```

Error I am getting is  :

> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to project-name.appspot.com/CrTwBuyNR2-log-2020-1-16-12-18.csv.'

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Firebase, I recommend initialising the bucket from `firebase-admin` instead of `@google-cloud/storage` directly. This will sort out permissions so that security rules are skipped.

In your code you have also incorrectly mixed the callback and `async`/`await` APIs. Because this code is running in a Cloud Function, I recommend exclusively using Promises and `async`/`await`.

The code below is a rewrite with the following changes:

- Code has been split into logical blocks
- No callback API usage (see [`File#download`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download))
- Each block will log and throw errors separately for easier debugging
- One-line log messages (i.e. no stack trace)
- Leaves full error logging to Cloud Functions (makes finding erroneous runs easier)

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.processLogs = functions.region('europe-west1').storage.object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {

    const bucketRef = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const fileRef = bucketRef.file(object.name);

    console.log('Processing "' + object.id + '"...');

    // 1) DOWNLOAD
    let [contents] = await fileRef.download()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('DOWNLOAD FAILED: ', (err.code ? err.code + ': ' : '') + err.message);
        throw err;
      });

    // 2) PARSE
    let dataToUpload = {};
    try {
      // Transform file contents
      dataToUpload = JSON.parse(contents);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('PARSE FAILED: ', (err.code ? err.code + ': ' : '') + err.message);
      throw err;
    }

    // 3) DATABASE SET
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref('path/to/data');
    await dbRef.set(dataToUpload)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('DATABASE SET FAILED: ', (err.code ? err.code + ': ' : '') + err.message);
        throw err;
      });

    // 4) CLEANUP
    await fileRef.delete()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('CLEANUP FAILED: ', (err.code ? err.code + ': ' : '') + err.message);
        throw err;
      });

    // 5) LOG SUCCESS
    console.log('SUCCEEDED');
  });
```

The log messages above can also be bundled into a helper function if desired:

```
function logAndRethrowError(err, name) {
  console.log((name || 'ERROR') + ': ', ((err.code ? err.code + ': ' : '') + err.message) || err);
  throw err;
}

// Usage:
let [contents] = await fileRef.download()
  .catch(err => logAndRethrowError(err, 'DOWNLOAD FAILED'));

try {
  // ...
} catch (err) { logAndRethrowError(err, 'PARSE FAILED') }
```

Comment: I think mixing callback and async/await was the problem. I originally tried with firebase-admin so that was not the case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with Security Rules not being set properly? Please try this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) or [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tyjqozrEPY).

For starters try this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

And if it proves successful set Storage Rules properly.

Comment: Yes. Besides if rules were not set it would fail always. But it works periodically.

Comment: It happens to the same user on different occasions?

Comment: Yes. File is being uploaded every minute. After some time processing fails. And then again it starts over.

Comment: Does it happen to everyone? Might it be a network issue?